# C++ locale names in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to localize a application using visual studio 2008 (C++).

Where can i find the valid locale names for:

**1.** US-ASCII
**2.** Unicode
**3.** Unicode (Big-Endian)
**4.** Japanese (Shift-JIS)
**5.** Japanese (JIS)
**6.** Japanese (JIS 0208-1990 and 0212-1990)